# Keep mesh of triangulation under complex valued transformation

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, complex, mesh

I try to make a quick tool for "plotting" complex valued functions. Therefore I generate a `Table` of complex valued points lying in the complex plane building a filled square.

```
(* map interval linear onto another *)
Transf[val_, A_, B_, a_, b_] := (val - A)*(b - a)/(B - A) + a; 

(* build up realpart *)
U[t_] := Transf[t, 0, numberOfPoints, -Size, Size];   

(* build up imaginary art *)
V[t_] := Transf[t, 0, numberOfPoints, -Size, Size];   

(* now generate points in the complex plane *)
A = Flatten[
   Table[
     Table[U[u] + I*V[v]      +       CenterX + I*CenterY,
        {u, 0, numberOfPoints}],
     {v, 0, numberOfPoints}
   ]
];

(* the function that is to be plotted *)
f[z_] = z^2;
```

I put all of this into a `Manipulate[]` to have control over `numberOfPoints`,`Size` which controls how wide the points spread and also the center of the square using `CenterX`, `CenterY`.

So far so good. Then I plot those points using

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"]
PlanarGraphPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ A, LabelPoints -> False],
```

I also use this to plot the points after they get mapped with `f[A]`. This looks like this:

[image: PlanarGraphExample]

Obviously Mathematica is recalculating the triangulation for the list `f[A]`. But I need Mathematica to draw triangles between those points, which shared a triangle before. Then one could get a better imagination on what the complex valued function `f[z] = z^2` does to the geometry of the square. How could I do that?

Answer (score 4):

```
numberOfPoints = 5; Size = 2; CenterX = 0; CenterY = 0; 

pgp = PlanarGraphPlot[ReIm @ A, LabelPoints -> False];
dg = DiscretizeGraphics[pgp];
prims = MeshCells[dg, All];
```

You can use `prims` with `MeshRegion`:

```
Quiet @ MeshRegion[ReIm @ f @ A, prims]
```

[image]

or with `GraphicsComplex` + `Graphics`:

```
Graphics[GraphicsComplex[ReIm @ f @ A, prims]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, construct a `Graph` object from `dg` and use `ReIm @ f @ A` as  its `VertexCoordinates`:

```
edges = MeshCells[dg, 1] /. Line -> Apply[UndirectedEdge];
vertices = Range[MeshCellCount[dg, 0]];

{g1, g2} = Graph[vertices, edges, VertexCoordinates -> ReIm @ #, 
     ImageSize -> Medium] & /@ {A, f @A};

Row[{g1, g2}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]